# Reference/Lecture notes on operational / functional calculus

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, functional-calculus, lecture-notes

Is there any lecture notes / books you can suggest for operational calculus? I just came across it, and I'm kinda of curious, I'm not sure I'm confusing it with "functional calculus"

Thanks

Comment: Might start from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_calculus). Heaviside calculus can quickly lead to fast answers bypassing hidebound combinatorics, like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4015569/proving-that-the-laguerre-polynomials-do-indeed-solve-the-differential-equation/4055534#4055534).

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few recommendations:

- Agnew' *Differential Equations* (specifically Ch.8; a freely borrowable copy is available at https://archive.org/details/differentialequa0000ralp/page/196/mode/2up)
- Dalton's *Symbolic Operators* (a freely borrowable copy is available at https://archive.org/details/symbolicoperator0000john)
- Berg's *Introduction to the Operational Calculus*
- McLachlan's *Modern Operational Calculus*
- Erdelyi's *Operational calculus and generalized functions*
- Wiener's "The operational calculus"

Here the first two references are classical books, the next three items are somewhat more contemporary books, and the final item is a classical paper.